Support for `sizeof T[n]` in the Frama-C framework
I am wondering how difficult it would be to add rudimentary support for something like sizeof T[n] (which to my knowledge is an explicit C construct for a variable length array), to be used in a dynamic allocation context such as malloc.
My experiments so far have shown that it is not supported (well?) in Frama-C. So my questions are: What would be required to implement it, in any capacity? What about kernel support? What about the development of an analysis domain for Eva, that can make use of such a feature in relations over allocated memory?

Here is an example that uses sizeof(T[n]) (supposing that malloc always succeeds):
#include <stdlib.h>

int *foo(int n, int x)
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int[n]));
    a[n - 1] = x;
    return a;
}

This is clearly not accepted by the Frama-C (version 29.0 [Copper]) kernel. It prints this message:
[kernel] mem.c:5: User Error: 
  Array length n is not a compile-time constant,
  and currently VLAs may only have their first dimension as variable.

Question: What could make this work? I do not expect it to be easy to add complete support.

Here is yet another example which makes use of a (pointer to a) variable length array. This compiles fine with gcc (GCC) 14.2.1 (w/ flag -c):
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *foo(int n, int x)
{
    int (*a)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[n])); // shamelessly crude cast
    assert(sizeof(*a) == sizeof(int[n])); // this holds (at runtime)
    (*a)[n - 1] = x;
    return (*a);
}

AFAIK, this is the most that the C language can "accommodate" the direct semantics I am hinting at, yet this vital information about *a is still lost upon the conclusion of foo(). Due to similar issues with the previous, this example is also not accepted by Frama-C.

I believe you mean sizeof applied to a variable length array (and not a dynamic array, which would be e.g. via malloc)? As in this question, which says that sizeof(int[x]) = x * sizeof(int) with x being evaluated?

Yes, you are right. I was aware that the expression involves a variable length array, but I went with the term dynamic to emphasise its use in a dynamic allocation (i.e. via malloc). In hindsight, I should have made that distinction explicit, rather than implicit. In any case, thanks for your comment.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "not well supported by Frama-C". At the parsing level, it is accepted by the kernel; at least I can write a program using it that parses. Eva does not evaluate it precisely, however, so that's probably what you mean? But even if it did, I believe the standard does not consider that it evaluates the size of a dynamically allocated array. Maybe you could provide a short C example in which the compiler produces a result and you'd like Frama-C to produce the same result? Such an mcve would help clarify the question.

I've written such a program in the past using that expression, that was rejected by WP ("User Error"), but accepted by Eva. That is evidence to me that the kernel does indeed support it, at least at a basic level. As for the dynamic part, C of course does not track the size of a variable length array, besides the variable that keeps the length. When that goes out of scope, the information is lost. I was wondering about the extent to which Frama-C could track that relation across function calls. Sure, I am happy to provide an example, when I get the chance. Thanks again for your reply.

As mentioned in your first comment, there is no essential difference between sizeof(T[n]) and n * sizeof(T). As a matter of taste, I have always found the first to be more expressive; regardless, my question is about storing that relation in the first place.

@anol I have expanded the question to include an example.

Basically, this requires to completely rearchitecture the way VLA are handled in Frama-C: currently, as a heritage of the original CIL library, they are treated as pointers allocated with a built-in alloca function (and freed at the end of the enclosing block). There are many other reasons to change that and make VLA first-class citizens in the Frama-C AST, but this is clearly not a completely trivial change.

Ah, that does help to explain some of the peculiarities. Thank you greatly for providing a background on the matter.
